# Batch to get location for all the processes that are running

Tags: windows, batch-file, process

i would like to build a batch that will look over the processes, for every process that it is running to get the location and put it in a variable like 
ex : there is process x1 running *poof magic* %var1% has the location of program x1 ... 
But it should do it for every process.. 
what i know is how to do it just for one process not all of them and i have to know the name of the process :

```
   wmic process where "name='aa.exe'" get ExecutablePath >dumpxkss.tmp
   more +1 dumpxkss.tmp >dumpxkss1.tmp
   for /f "delims=" %%x in (dumpxkss.tmp) do set Build=%%x
   set build1=%Build:~0,-8%
```

but in this case if there are more aa.exe processes it won t work..

so i want to get the path for every process no matter the name ...
please help ??

Comment: Did you mean that you want get all the process that running on your computer with their path and their command Line ?

Comment: yeah that's what i meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quite obvious: in your `for` loop you only set a variable - and set it again and set it again for every line of the textfile. So your `set build1` can only work with the last value, all the previous values got overwritten. You just have to expand your `for` loop:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
wmic process where "name='aa.exe'" get ExecutablePath >dumpxkss.tmp
more +1 dumpxkss.tmp >dumpxkss1.tmp
for /f "delims=" %%x in (dumpxkss.tmp) do (
  set Build=%%x
  set build1=!Build:~0,-8!
  echo !build1!
)
```

Also read about [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

You can shorten your code to:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%x in ('wmic process where "name='aa.exe'" get ExecutablePath') do (
  set Build=%%x
  echo !Build:~0,-8!
)
```

Comment: nononono, you see that didn't solve the problem .. i want this command to run for every existing process not only for aa.exe

Comment: then just delete `where "name='aa.exe'"` (although I'm not sure, what `%Build:~0,-8%` is supposed to mean...)

Comment: yea , if i remove    where "name='aa.exe'"     and run it as administrator it work's just fine. thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

Give a try for this batch file :

```
@echo off
set LogFile=Running_Process.txt
If Exist %LogFile% Del %LogFile%
WMIC /APPEND:%LogFile% PROCESS GET Caption,CommandLine>Nul
start "" %LogFile%
```

Comment: well thanks for the work but i don't wanna log them .. i want to get every location of every running process in a variable